# Float with 'unnecessary' digits

Tags: ruby, floating-point, number-formatting

I need to make a number out of the string. to do that i use well known maneuver looking something like this:

```
Float(string_var) rescue nil
```

This works nicely, however I do have a tiny, little problem. If a string is `"2.50"`, variable I get is `2.5`. Is it even possible to create Float object with 'unnecessary' 0 digit at the end? can I literally translate `"2.50"` into `2.50` ?

Comment: Float("2,50") rescue nil gives nil not 2,5

Comment: i edited the question, its legit now

Comment: As far as I can tell, you seem to be looking for `printf("%.2f", theFloat)`. The 0 at the end is there (`2.5 == 2.50 == 2.500000000`), I guess it's just not being displayed if you print out the plain float value.

Comment: Float("2.5").to_f rescue nil

Comment: From the mathematical standpoint, 2.5 and 2.50 are the same number. If you care about the trailing zero, perhaps you don't need Float at all. Why are you converting to Float to begin with?

Comment: i need this value to eventually become number i can perform math operations on. and i need the trailing 0 for displaying purposes

Comment: @Leo "displaying purposes" means formatting which belongs in your view.  [`ActiveSupport::NumberHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper.html) provides several helper methods.

Comment: @Leo: There are no "hidden / unhidden" zeroes in a Float. `2.5 == 2.50` evaluates to `true`.  If you want to "remember", how the string representation of the value had been before, you simply have to keep the string around as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is no, given the question, as any Float, when examined, will use Float's `to_s` function, eliciting an answer without trailing zeroes.

Float will always give you a numeric value that can be interpreted any way you wish, though. In your example, you *will* get a float value (given a string that is a parsable float). What you are asking then, is how to display that value *with* trailing zeroes. To do that, you will be turning the float value back into a string.

Easiest way to accomplish that is to use the format given by one of your respondents, namely

```
string_var = "2.50"
float_value = Float(string_var) rescue nil # 2.5
with_trailing_zeroes = "%0.2f" % float_value # '2.50'
```